# first order differences along a given axis in NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
#compute first differences of 1d array
from numpy import *

x = arange(10)
y = zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1,len(x)):
    y[i] = x[i] - x[i-1]
print y
```

The above code works but there must be at least one easy, pythonesque way to do this without having to use a for loop.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Elalfer I think he's just using `arange()` as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this exactly the kind of loop numpy elementwise operations is designed for.  You just need to learn to take the right slices of the arrays.

```
x = numpy.arange(10)
y = numpy.zeros(x.shape)

y[1:] = x[1:] - x[:-1]

print y
```

Answer (score 10):

What about:

```
diff(x)
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 5):

several NumPy builtins will do the job--in particular, *diff, ediff1d*, and *gradient*.

i suspect ***ediff1d*** is the better choice for the specific cast described in the OP--unlike the other two, ediff1d is acdtually directed/limited to this specific use case--ie, first-order differences along a single axis (or axis of a 1D array).

```
>>> import numpy as NP
>>> x = NP.random.randint(1, 10, 10)
>>> x
  array([4, 6, 6, 8, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4])

>>> NP.ediff1d(x)
  array([ 2,  0,  2, -7,  1, -1,  0,  4, -1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pattern I used a lot for a while:

`from itertools import izip`

`d = [a-b for a,b in izip(x[1:],x[:-1])]`

Answer (score 1):

```
y = [item - x[i - 1] for i, item in enumerate(x[1:])]
```

If you need to access the index of an item while looping over it, `enumerate()` is the Pythonic way. Also, a list comprehension is, in this case, more readable.

Moreover, you should never use wild imports (`from numpy import *`). It will always import more than you need and leads to unnecessary ambiguity. Rather, just `import numpy` or import what you need, e.g.

```
from numpy import arange, zeros
```